# Why does my code only throw an error when debugger is not attached?

Tags: javascript

Have you ever had such a problem? Your code works with debugger on but when it is off it doesn't work??

So above I have 2 links to screen recordings, showing how when debugger is active my code works but when not it throws an error. If anyone is brave enough to look at my codepen of the issue I would be grateful. (Debugger doesn't work in codepen but if you were to take the code and put it in your editor you will see that it workers when debugger is on.)  https://codepen.io/oliver-saintilien/pen/jOrQBLv

stackoverflow says that I **MUST** include code whenever I use a codepen link, however the code is a bit involved. So I will just post the code where there error occurs, but just remember it actually works if I have debug attached.

```js
//Uses path to return nested object
const traverse = (obj, path) => {
  console.log(`1 time`);
  return path.split(".").reduce((object, key) => object[key], obj);
};
```

Comment: How did you cause that panel to pop up after selecting text?

Comment: Yeah that's all in my codepen code(in answer to how I am getting that panel to pop up) however to cut to the chase I actually just solved my own problem although I don't quite understand the science behind it why this fixes it.  For some reason my changing 

`let parentFolder = this[0].outerText.replace(/\s/g, '')`

to 

`let parentFolder = this[0].text.replace(/\s/g, '')`

causes it to work now without debugger on although I do not  know why, but hey it works.

Just to be clear, my using the method `.text` instead of `.outerText` is what made the difference.

Comment: Your answer to my question is "go read hundreds of lines of code to figure it out?" :-) Nobody's going to do that.  But glad that you got it sorted out.

Comment: Yeah I hear you on that, don't blame  you either, but yeah thanks, I'm happy too

Comment: Then, when you use the debugger, the main thread stop and timer function has chance to occur and run.

Comment: @Vahid hey there, thanks for your input. when you say timer function, do you mean functions like setInterval() and setTimeout()?

Comment: @OliverSaintilien Yes, I mean something like these two functions setInterval(), setTimeout(), or a library which needed and need time to load when page is loading.

Comment: Cool thanks will take that into consideration next time if it happens again

Answer (score 0):

For some reason by changing

`let parentFolder = this[0].outerText.replace(/\s/g, '')`

to

`let parentFolder = this[0].text.replace(/\s/g, '')`

causes it to work now without debugger on although I do not know why, but hey it works. Just to be clear, my using the method `.text` instead of `.outerText` is what made the difference.